# disable jQuery autocomplete dropdown

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

This is rather a simple question, but how do I disable the dropdown of the jQuery Autocomplete? When a user starts typing, I run my own function on the response callback. I don't need anything else to appear. This is what I have:

```
            $( "#search" ).autocomplete({
                source: "/app/friends",
                minLength: 2,
                response: function( event, ui ) {
                    $(".ui-menu-item").hide(); //i hoped this would work
                    display(ui.content);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Try commenting out the `display(ui.content);` line.

Comment: Not sure why that would do anything since it's my own method. But it didn't work.

Comment: Oh, ok - didn't realise that was your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [the documentation for the plugin](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-disabled), there is an `open` event that fires when the menu opens. You can put some code in that event to hide the drop down:

```
$( "#search" ).autocomplete({
    source: "/app/friends",
    minLength: 2,
    response: function( event, ui ) {
        display(ui.content);
    },
    open: function( event, ui ) {
        $(".ui-autocomplete").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: **NOTE:** that there needs to be added a `,` before `open:` for proper **syntax**, otherwise your (java)script won't work properly.

(Since edits need at least 6 characters (why?) I had to post this as comment)