# Remove/Hide autocomplete list item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I want to display result in live from autocomplete results ! So I write code on `response` & `select` for display live results in table. So I want to remove (hide) item from `#autocomplete` under list ! I can't even hide by css

> .ui-menu,.ui-autocomplete { display:none;}

Is there any option for removing autocomplete list item (not remove source data) ?

```js
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
  source: [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby" ]
  ,
  select:function(event,ui) {
    Display([ui.item]);
  },
  response:function(event,ui) {
    Display(ui.content);
  }
});

function Display(d) {
  var result = "";
  for(var i in d) {
    result += "<tr><td>"+i+"</td><td>"+d[i].value+"</td></tr>";
  }
  
  $("#result tbody").html(result);
}
```

```css
table {
table-layout:fixed;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
th,td {
width:30px;
height:30px;
border : 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<label for="autocomplete">Select a programming language: </label>
<input id="autocomplete">

<table id="result">
<thead><th>No</th><th>Name</th></thead>
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20735013/disable-jquery-autocomplete-dropdown. You may try to add `open: function( event, ui ) { $(".ui-autocomplete").hide(); }`